# Django custom ManyRelatedManager for multi-record inheritance

Tags: python, django, inheritance

I have the following object structure:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16)

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    cars = models.ManyToManyField(Car, through='Relationship')
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='childrens')

class Relationship(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    love = models.BooleanField(_('love status'), default=True, db_index=True)
```

The logic is of the models is:

- A **Person** may be have another **Person** (children, for instance-ForeignKey on 'self').
- A **cars** (many related manager) should return a cars of the current related person + a cars, that his father (if exists) have (inheritance).
- A **children** can't **add** to self a **car**, that his father already have (inheritance).
- A **relationship_set** manager should work by the same logic of **cars** manager (if a father loves his car, then a children should love it too.

This logic looks like **inheritance**. I can't implement this logic by [Multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance), because a **children** may have other **children**. Maybe there are some ideas like multi-record inheritance?

Comment: Can't you just implement simple models properties? For example: `def loves(self, car): return self.cars.filter(car=car, love=True).count() == 1 or self.parent.loves(car)`

Comment: @Germano firstly there is no field 'car' or 'love' in Car model. Secondly I need to implement this by related managers 'cars' and 'relationship_set'

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood your question, then. The simplest way to do it is to create a custom method on your `Person` model that returns the queryset you want. Alternatively, if you use django 1.7, you can create a manager from a custom queryset.